# Improper locking vulnerabilities due to mutex?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mutex, dispose

My windows project periodically scanned by Checkmarx.

Rightnow, I am getting

> "Improper_Locking"

vulnerabilities due to wrong Mutex implementation, I think.

Below is the code snippet for Mutex:

```
  Mutex TuningClientInstanceMutex;

  /// <summary>
  /// Method used to configure the inter process communication
  /// </summary>
  private void ConfigureInterProcessCommunication()
  {
     try
     {
        // Try to open existing mutex
        Mutex.OpenExisting(Mutex_Name);

        // Tuning Client must be already running
        return;
     }
     catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException)
     {
        // Not implemented.
     }

     // Flag that the application is available to accept automated calls
     // Create the mutex that will allow automated listeners to know that we have started
     TuningClientInstanceMutex= new Mutex(true, Mutex_Name);

     // Some other code is here.
     // ..........
     // ..........
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
     if (TuningClientInstanceMutex!= null)
     {
        TuningClientInstanceMutex.Close();
     }
  }
```

What should I improve here to mitigate the "Improper_Locking" vulnerabilities ?

Comment: Is there any more detail that Checkmarx gave you? "Improper locking" is incredibly vague...

Comment: @canton7,
 

"The Mutex object is used to take a synchronization lock by method ConfigureInterProcessCommunication, at line 204 of Applications\TuningClient\App.xaml.cs. However, this lock will never be released, possibly leading to deadlocks or unconstrained resource consumption.    "    


              


I found above description, when vulnerability occurred

Comment: Assuming that `Dispose` is actually called, that looks fine to me. I'm assuming line 204 is the `TuningClientInstanceMutex= new Mutex(true, Mutex_Name);` one?

Comment: Might be related to the call to `Mutex.OpenExisting(Mutex_Name)` as you are not doing anything with the result.

Comment: @canton7, 
Line 204 is `private void ConfigureInterProcessCommunication()` , but Checkmarx is highlighting  `TuningClientInstanceMutex= new Mutex(true, Mutex_Name); ` in yellow color means, this line is creating some problem.

Comment: @user14285851 the problem might be if the line itself, or what follows, throws an exception. In that case, the mutex is not handled. Wrap it in a `try.. catch` statement, handle the mutex and `throw;` for propagation.

Comment: @Andrei15193,

My project has some more classes, which contains only `TuningClientInstanceMutex= new Mutex(true, Mutex_Name); `  .
They don't have `Mutex.OpenExisting(Mutex_Name)` , but still getting same issue for those classes.

Comment: @user14285851 yeah, it's most likely code after `TuningClientInstanceMutex = new Mutex(true, Mutex_Name);` that might throw exceptions that in turn will leave your mutex in an open state. `TuningClientInstanceMutex = new Mutex(true, Mutex_Name); try { ... } catch { TuningClientInstanceMutex.Close(); throw; }` may fix the issue.

Comment: Hi @canton7 , Andrei15193,   Thanks for your suggestions. It helped.